Meilisearch: Self-hosted cloud deployment network connection stalling
I'm trying to work with self-hosted Meilisearch deployed on Openshift but it seems to be searching very slowly. I plan to increase the available resources but I don't think that is the main issue as each search network request seems to be stalling and waiting for the previous one to finish.
I can't imagine this is how it is supposed to be working but has anyone who has worked with Meilisearch before have any ideas about what might be going on?
All of the grey bars in the screenshot below are times it is showing stalled under the connection start section of the timing information. When I run the apps locally it search fine without stalling so I think it might be a network policy issue or something along those lines
I tried increasing the resources and running it locally

